# Django: New record for manytomany relationship at insert

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

Say I have two basic classes, one with a ManyToMany relationship to the other:

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    abc = models.TextField()
    test = models.ManyToManyField(Bar)

class Bar(models.Model):
    zyx = models.TextField()
```

And then I create a Django form for Foo:

```
class FooForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Foo
        fields = ["abc", "test"]
```

This will create a form with a TextArea for me to input the value of the new `Foo`'s `abc` variable, as well as a listbox to link it to one or more `Bar` objects. What I would like to do for this particular form, is instead of the listbox for the `Bar` objects, be able to create one (and only one) new `Bar` at the same time (i.e., display a second TextArea for the value of `Bar`'s `zyx`) and then link that new `Bar` to the new `Foo`. The ManyToMany relationship comes in later on in editing, but at creation, I want exactly one `Bar` tied to the one new `Foo`.

Is it possible to do this all at once by POSTing the form, or am I going to have to use some javascript and AJAX to actually create the `Bar` first, get its new ID, and link the new `Foo` to that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It *is* possible, but I'm not sure a `ModelForm` would do that for you.

---

#### However, you can easily do it on your own:

Set up the forms for the user to fill-in:

- Create a form to let the user input `abc` (that *could* be a `ModelForm`)
- Create a [formset](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/formsets/) out of a form that let the user enter an arbitrary number of `zyx` to create related `Bar` instances. (Again, formset of `ModelForm` is OK)

When processing the `POST` data, do the following:

1. Validate the form and the formset are valid
2. Insert the new instances
3. Add your new `Bar` instances to your new `Foo`'s `Bar` ManyToMany relationship

---

*Small tip: remember that `ModelForm.save` returns the instance!*

Comment: Assuming I would only ever want one new Bar at the creation of the new Foo, this should be simpler and not require the formset, correct?

Comment: Since my `Bar` only has one field, I think the easiest thing to do following your guide is just to create an extra field under the `Foo` ModelForm ( `zyx = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea)` ) and then use that to create and link a new `Bar` in the view handling the POST. I appreciate the help!

Comment: @Joseph It does, but if you need to future proof your code, using `ModelForm`'s can sometimes be very useful, as it will save you time to just add a new field to the `ModelForm`! : )

Comment: You're right, and I'm already realizing this as I need to do something similar for a third class, so I will go with ModelForm. 

Question- how are the forms differentiated in the view from request.POST? Is Django just going to know to put the right data in the right forms?

Comment: @Joseph If the form have non-conflicting fields, yes. Otherwise, [use the `prefix` kwarg](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2374224/django-working-with-multiple-forms) when you instantiate the form!