# django submit two different forms with one submit button

Tags: python, django, forms

is it possible to submit two different forms, with one submit button in django?
i have one form called "instrument" and 4 equal forms "config". now i'd like to submit always one config and instrument. e.g. instrument + config 1, and instrument + config 2. and every config have its own submit button.

i have tried it with one button in the config form:

```
<input onclick="submitForms()" class="btn btn-primary cfg" type="submit" value="Start" >
```

and call a js function 'onclick':

```
submitForms = function(){
    console.log('ok'); //only for testing
    document.forms["firstForm"].submit();
    document.forms["secondForm"].submit();
}
```

this is my method in the views.py:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
        form1 = dataproviderInstrumentForm(request.POST)
        form2 = dynamicTimeseriesForm(request.POST)
        print(request.POST)
        if form1.is_valid() or form2.is_valid(): 
            # do some stuff

else:
    form1 = dataproviderInstrumentForm() # an unbound form
    form2 = dynamicTimeseriesForm() # an unbound form
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I submit multiple forms with a single submit button in django?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15124567/how-do-i-submit-multiple-forms-with-a-single-submit-button-in-django)

Comment: yeah i have seen this post, but isn't possible to do that without a formset only with a js function?

Answer (score 82, accepted):

Instead of having multiple `<form ..>` tags in html, use only one `<form>` tag and add fields of all forms under it.

Example in template

```
<form >
    {{ form1.as_p }}
    {{ form2.as_p }}
    {{ form3.as_p }}
</form>
```

So when user submits the form you will get all forms data in view, then you can do what you are doing in view. As

```
if request.method == 'POST':
        form1 = Form1(request.POST)
        form2 = Form2(request.POST)
        print(request.POST)
        if form1.is_valid() or form2.is_valid():
```

Its better to use [`form prefix`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/api/#prefixes-for-forms) in such cases.

So you can do

```
if request.method == 'POST':
        form1 = Form1( request.POST,prefix="form1")
        form2 = Form2( request.POST,prefix="form2")
        print(request.POST)
        if form1.is_valid() or form2.is_valid(): 
else:
        form1 = Form1(prefix="form1")
        form2 = Form2(prefix="form2")
```

Comment: this looks fine if i would submit all forms at once, but i'd like to submit one config form and the instrument form at the same time. so if i submit the second config form with his own submit button the instrument form should also submit. and the submit button for the other 3 config should do the same. always submit the config form which submit button i have clicked and the instrument form.

Comment: what if my forms submit to different pieces of code and then gather again to single view ?

Answer (score 4):

Extending the **@Rohan** answer and adding more control on forms.

**Not dependent forms/Without relationship/Save any form from multiple forms**

Check individually each form to check which form are not valid. Then store them into context if contain errors or redirect them.

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    form1 = Form1( request.POST,prefix="form1")
    form2 = Form2( request.POST,prefix="form2")
    
    if form1.is_valid():
       # save them    
       
       # context['form1_message'] = 'Form1 saved'
    else: 
       #save them into context
       context['form1']= form1
    
    if form2.is_valid():
       # save them    
       # context['form2_message'] = 'Form2 saved'
    else: 
       #save them into context
       context['form2']= form2

    if form1.is_valid() and  form2.is_valid(): 
       #that's mean both form is valid and saved successfully 
       return redirect('page')
    else:
        return render('/page', context)


else:
    form1 = Form1(prefix="form1")
    form2 = Form2(prefix="form2")
```

**Dependent forms/Modelform(1-1,1-m)/Relationship form**

One Parent form and one child form that depends on Parent form. if both forms are saved or checked errors at same time then we will use this method.

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    form1 = Form1( request.POST,prefix="form1")
    form2 = Form2( request.POST,prefix="form2")
    
    if not form1.is_valid():
       #save them into context
       context['form1']= form1
    
    if not form2.is_valid():
       #save them into context
       context['form2']= form2

    if form1.is_valid() and  form2.is_valid(): 
       #that's mean both form is valid and saved successfully 
       return redirect('page')
    else:
        return render('/page', context)


else:
    form1 = Form1(prefix="form1")
    form2 = Form2(prefix="form2")
```

Answer (score 0):

i didnt get much luck with the above but ive been using crispy forms. So the way i did it finally i had different forms but in crispy forms i set the    self.helper.form_tag = False, that way i only carry the Html form tags and the rest eventhough are forms and i can specify it in html i can submit all data together

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).