# use a custom form inside a template which is linked to another view django

Tags: html, django, templates

How can i use my custom form called PayForm inside a template (Post.html) which is the template of a view called Post I tried to point both of the views to the same template but as i was told you can't point two views to the same template so i am currently stuck on this

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.urls import reverse
from PIL import Image

# Create your models here.


class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    content = models.TextField(default="---")
    current_price = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    reduction = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    original_price = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    Status = models.CharField(max_length=5, default="✓")
    img = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    sold = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    endday = models.CharField(max_length=30, default="apr 27, 2018 16:09:00")


    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-created']

        def __unicode__(self):
            return u'%s'% self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('Products.views.post', args=[self.slug])

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title



class Payment(models.Model):
    Author = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    Product = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    Payment_ID = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    Status = models.CharField(max_length=5, default="X")
    Review_result = models.CharField(max_length=255, default="Not yet reviewed")
    Address = models.CharField(max_length=255, default='')
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-created']

        def __unicode__(self):
            return u'%s'% self.Status

    def __str__(self):
        return self.Status
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render, render_to_response , get_object_or_404, redirect
from .models import Post
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login, logout
from .forms import RegistrationForm, PayForm


def index(request):
    posts=Post.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'Index.html', {"posts": posts})


def post(request, slug):
    return render(request, 'post.html', {'post': get_object_or_404(Post, slug=slug)})

def new_payment(request):

    template ='payment.html'
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = PayForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('index')
        else:
            print('form invalid')

    else:
        form = PayForm({'Author':request.user.username})

    context = {
        'form' : form,
    }
    return render(request, template, context)
```

**forms.py**

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from .models import Payment, Post

class RegistrationForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField(required=True)
    first_name = forms.CharField(required=True)
    last_name = forms.CharField(required=True)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = (
                'username',
                'first_name',
                'last_name',
                'email',
                'password1',
                'password2',
            )

    def save(self, commit=True):
        user = super(RegistrationForm, self).save(commit=False)
        user.first_name = self.cleaned_data['first_name']
        user.last_name = self.cleaned_data['last_name']
        user.email = self.cleaned_data['email']

        if commit:
            user.save()

        return user

class PayForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta: 

        model = Payment
        fields = ['Author', 'Product', 'Payment_ID', 'Address']
```

If someone can help me with this it would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Possible duplicate of [django submit two different forms with one submit button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18489393/django-submit-two-different-forms-with-one-submit-button)

Comment: That's not what i wanted to do i want to use the payment form inside the post view  like to set the curent post's slug as a default value for the product field in payment

Comment: Are you trying to get two `forms` on the same `view`?

Comment: no i have one form which is new_payment and i want to display it on the post template

Answer (score 0):

If you have already created `new_payment_form.html`(or whatever you have called it) you can simply add to the `post.html` by using the `{% include %}` tag surrounded with appropriate `<form>` tags and whatever you need to go with it. The {% include %} essentially copies and pastes all the code from whatever file you have inside the tag. And a general rule, `Product` means class and `product` means variable or field.

```
# new_payment_form.html is the name of your html file. 
# template_path is the directory to your template. 
<form>
    {% include 'template_path/new_payment_form.html' %}
    <button> # submit button
</form>
```

However, you still need to process it in the view.

```
def post(request, slug):
    """
    (all the if: else: stuff)
    """
    # Set new_payment product
    new_payment = PayForm(initial={'Product': slug})

    return render(request, 'post.html', {'post': get_object_or_404(Post, slug=slug), 'new_payment': new_payment})
```

You will probably rewrite your view, and there are some details to figure out, but that should get you headed in the right direction. You might want to change `slug` to a product `id` or `pk`.

Comment: Still nothing :(

Comment: Did your form display?

Comment: only the submit button

Comment: The {% include %} gets put into the `<body>` where you want it to go, not in the `<head>`.

Comment: still only the submit button

Comment: Do you have form tags around it? Does your form work by itself?

Comment: I updated the answer. You have to put the include where that form goes in your file

Comment: I'm giving up on this I will find another way

Comment: Here’s the Django reference [look for include](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/templates/builtins/)