# Django form looping closing tag

Tags: html, django, forms

i'm trying to submit more than one form with one button using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18489593/10284387) as an example.

The difference is that i'm adding forms dynamically using this code:

```
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
<form method="POST" action="{% url 'App:Submit' %}">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% for form in forms %}
    <h3>Hour {{ form.Hour }}: </h3>
    <form>
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form|crispy }}
    </form>
    <br>
    {% endfor %}
    <br>
    <div class="col text-center">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Send</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Using this example, in Chrome, the main `<form>` tag with the action closes after the first loop.

Any idea why this is happening? Thanks