# How to make a single form for two related models?

Tags: django, validation, django-models, django-forms

I have 2 models, one is a User models and other is a profile model. Now I want to make a single form the validates and saves the data during registration.

I have got both the forms in a single form tag and my view receives the data via request.POST, but how do I get the form validation to work?

Here is my view -

```
class IndexView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'index.html'
    register_form = RegistrationForm(instance=User())
    broker_profile_form = BrokerProfileForm(instance=BrokerProfile())

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        user_type_form = UserTypeForm()


        return render(request, self.template_name,
                      {
                       'login_form': self.register_form,
                       'broker_profile_form': self.broker_profile_form,
                      }
        )


    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        print 'post data'
        print request.POST
        print self.register_form.is_valid()
        for field in self.register_form:
            print field.errors
```

Comment: Please read other posts : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770810/multiple-models-in-a-single-django-modelform

Comment: @Bilou06 I'm having problems in displaying the errors back in the template

Answer (score 0):

**First**, read this answer to a similar question : https://stackoverflow.com/a/2374240/4789005 and use prefix

**Second**, when the view is hit with `post` you should get the `form` from the request. If not, you will never get the data from the request.

```
Class IndexView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'index.html'

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form1 = MyFormClass(prefix='some_prefix_1')
        form2 = MyFormClass(prefix='some_prefix_2')
        return render(request, self.template_name,
                      {
                       'form1': form1,
                       'form2': form2
                      }
        )


    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form1 = MyFormClass(request.POST, prefix='some_prefix_1')
        for field in form1:
            ...
```

Comment: Yes I have done this, I am able to access the post data, I am also able to save it. But I am unable to send back the error messages if any.

Comment: I am not sure of your problem then. Is it form validation https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/forms/validation/#form-field-default-cleaning ?